# Is there a way to simplify my code?

Tags: java, encryption

Hello for a project I have to encrypt and decrypt a txt file. Everything is working fine and the program works exactly how I want it, I was just curious if there is a way to simplify one section of it

```
int first;
            int second;
            int third;
            int fourth;

            long M = 0;

            if (toDecrypt.length() == 4) {
                first = ((toDecrypt.charAt(0) - '0') * 1000);
                second = ((toDecrypt.charAt(1) - '0') * 100);
                third = ((toDecrypt.charAt(2) - '0') * 10);
                fourth = toDecrypt.charAt(3) - '0';

                M = first + second + third + fourth;
            }

            if (toDecrypt.length() == 3) {
                first = ((toDecrypt.charAt(0) - '0') * 100);
                second = ((toDecrypt.charAt(1) - '0') * 10);
                third = toDecrypt.charAt(2) - '0';

                M = first + second + third;
            }

            if (toDecrypt.length() == 2) {
                first = ((toDecrypt.charAt(0) - '0') * 10);
                second = toDecrypt.charAt(1) - '0';

                M = first + second;
            }

            long temp = M;
```

What this section is doing is taking in my encrypted file line by line which are in numbers and decrypting it. The line can have anywhere from 2-4 numbers per line. Like I said the code is working perfectly I was just curious if I am able to simplify this or if I am overthinking it and if it works don't bother changing it. I suppose my overall question here is in the real world do coders/programmers attempt to make their programs more simplified or is it whatever option works first is what they go with?

Comment: Use some kind of loop

Comment: Meaningful names would be a start.  Things like `M` and `first` have no context or bearing of understanding outside of your code.

Comment: `first = ((toDecrypt.charAt(0) - '0') * Math.pow (10, toDecrypt.length() -1)`

Comment: Why not just `M = Long.parseLong(toDecrypt);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
long M = 0;
int hash = 1;
for(int i = toDecrypt.length() - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
{
    M += (toDecrypt.charAt( i ) - '0') * hash;
    hash *= 10;
}
```

If you're just trying to read numbers from a file though, have you considered using something like a `Scanner`? You could use `nextInt()` function to get each number from the file. It seems like your loop is just converting a `String` to a number, right?